# Determining if the movement of a robot is possible in a row

Tags: python

> A robot can move in one step from cell X to cell Y if and only if the distance between the centers of the cells X and Y measured in meters is equal to the sum of integers contained in X and Y. It then returns the index of the cell which the above condition does not meet which is the index only `[0, 1, 4]` and its value is `[3, 1, 0]`.

How can I improve my code and reduce the time complexity?

```
def row_walk(matrix):

    result = []
    x = []
    y = []
    for i, r1 in enumerate(matrix):
        y.append(i)
        for j, r2 in enumerate(matrix):
            if r1+r2 == abs(i-j) and not j <= i:
                x.append((i, j))
    result.append((list({el for tup in x for el in tup})))

    z = []
    for t1 in y:
        if t1 not in result[0]:
            z.append(t1)
    return z

if __name__=="__main__":
    matrix = [3, 1, 3, 2, 0, 0]
    print(row_walk(matrix))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you are defining too many variables.  Instead of making a list of tuples and then converting it to a flattened list with a different name, you should make the list out of numbers in the first place.  It would also be better to use a set instead of a list.  Your `if` statement is a little odd.  `not j <= i` is the same as `j > i`, but harder to read.  If `j` must be greater than `i`, why does your first check include `abs()`?  Since `j > i` is an easier operation than the other check, it should come first.  That way, if it is `False`, the other check won't even be evaluated and the whole thing is more efficient.  You could also use a comprehension instead of a four-line `for` loop:

```
def row_walk(matrix):
    used = set()
    for i, r1 in enumerate(matrix):
        for j, r2 in enumerate(matrix):
            if j > i and r1+r2 == j-i:
                used.update((i, j))
    return [x for x in range(len(matrix)) if x not in used]
```

If you can use a set instead of a list, you can use a better `return` statement:

```
return used.symmetric_difference(range(len(matrix))
```

This all assumes that you are using Python 3.  If you are using Python 2, use `xrange()` instead of `range()`.  Although `range()` still exists in Python 2, it creates a list instead of an iterator.